# Jquery fade in, fade out some elements together

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I need to fade out and fade in some child elements in `<div>` like in Toni Almeida'a answer:

[Fade in and out image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735259/1534785)

```
 <div class="display" id="slideshow">
            <a class="slice" href="myUrl1">
                <div class="caption">Some text1...</div>
                <img src="AnyUrl1" width="360" height="300"/>
            </a>

            <a class="slice" href="myUrl2">
                <div class="caption">Some text2...</div>
                <img src="AnyUrl2" width="360" height="300"/>
            </a>

            <a class="slice" href="myUrl3">
                <div class="caption">Some text3...</div>
                <img src="AnyUrl3" width="360" height="300"/>
            </a>
           .......
</div>
```

How should I edit the code in that answer?

Comment: Are you wanting to fade in/out that entire div at once?

Comment: yes, to fade out/in all elements group (div, a and image) entire div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my `js` code modified to work with your `html`:

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    count = ($("#slideshow").find(".slice:nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    $("#slideshow").find(".slice:nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HewAd/

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 1;
var $slideShow = $("#slideshow");
var $prevSlice;
var $nextSlice;
setInterval(function() {
    $prevSlice = $slideShow.find(".slice:nth-child("+count+")");
    count = ($prevSlice.next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    $nextSlice = $slideShow.find(".slice:nth-child("+count+")");
    $prevSlice.fadeOut();
    $nextSlice.fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/308/

Is it correct?